# What does the abbreviation VtC mean?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

What does the abbreviation **VtC** stand for? I saw it [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/why-would-a-u-s-politician-want-to-be-pro-zionist) in the comments.

Comment: Vote to Close.  The question will get many of them, because it belongs in _Meta._

Comment: Another variant, albeit less commonly used, is "VtR". You decide what it stands for. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VtC is an abbreviation of [Vote to Close](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), which is something you can do once you reach 3000 reputation.